# Establish PPP via serial cable

Tags: ppp

I am trying to enable PPP via USB serial cable from my laptop to my rpi. As per http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection, I have entered the following on my laptop:

```
sudo pppd noauth proxyarp /dev/tty.usbserial-FTGCC2MV 115200 10.0.0.1:10.0.0.2 passive local maxfail 0 nocrtscts xonxoff
```

However, when I try to ping 10.0.0.2, nothing happens:

```
ping 10.0.0.2 # Does not provide any response
```

How do I establish PPP via serial cable ? I am running Fedora Linux on my laptop and raspbian on the pi.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Did you also run `sudo pppd noauth` on the Pi? Did running `pppd` on the laptop yield any output or did you check the logfiles after starting it?

Comment: The one above did not yield any output

`sudo pppd noauth` on the pi does yield stuff, but chunks of random ascii characters